# How to fix permission denied for home folder with Apache in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, permission, apache, webserver

I recently activated the apache that ships with OS X Mavericks.
I followed some tutorial to set up the web-server, however. When I browse to my home-filter at `http://localhost/~nazeem`, I get the following error: `You don't have permission to access /~nazeem/ on this server.`

**Installation steps**

To setp up the webserver, I took the following steps:

1. activated the webserver with command: `apachectl start`
2. enabled PHP by checking if the module is loaded
3. checked if the home folder module is loaded
4. made the user based configuration file, in `/etc/apache2/users/nazeem.conf`
   The content is as follows:

   `<Directory "/Users/nazeem/Development/Websites/">
           Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride All
   </Directory>`

**Permissions**

~/nazeem : drwxr-xr-x+
~/nazeem/Development : drwxr-xr-x
~/nazeem/Development/Websites : drwxr-xr-x

**Log**

The apache log says the following:

```
[Mon May 19 21:22:57 2014] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Users/nazeem/Sites
```

In My opinion this is remarkable, as the path `/Users/nazeem/Sites` is nog what I defined in my user configuration.

**Versions**

OS X Mavericks 10.9.3
Apache 2.2.26

***Does anybody know how to solve this?***

Comment: If you didn't restart apache after making the configuration file changes, then it would end up using the default for your user ( ~/Sites ).  Run "apachectl restart" and see if it works like you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already did that, and the result stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

In your computer's main apache config file, there is a designated "DocumentRoot", which appears to be set to ~/Sites - hence /Users/nazeem/Sites.

Try setting a document root in your /etc/apache2/users/nazeem.conf file, something like this:

DocumentRoot "/Users/nazeem/Development/Websites"

That's NOT within the Directory section of your nazeem.theconf file.

Note that the main apache config probably also designates the directory aliased as "cgi-bin". It's probably /Library/Webserver/CGI-Executables. Either use that directory for your executables, or post a follow-up about ScriptAlias settings.

And of course after any change to your apache config:

sudo apachectl restart

HTH